# How to fix broken "newline" from Mac to Windows

Tags: linux, windows, macos, unix, newlines

I have been given a set of python codes (`.py`) which were written on Mac. Unfortunately, when I open them on windows (pycharm, notepad, even word), there are no line breaks. I asked for .txt versions of the file, but the problem persists, likely since Max/Unix and Windows use different newline characters.

Is there a way I can fix this without needing access to Mac/Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the files in utf-8 encoding to solve your problem with newlines. On a Mac you could use Atom, and on Windows you could use Atom or Notepad++.

Comment: In the end, the other teammate had to repair their files, as there were no newline characters at all, so I could not fix it. Still accepting the answer for future reference for other users.